# How to get values from childNodes in PHP DOM

Tags: php

I need some help here.

```
<div class="item-compromisso">
    <div class="compromisso-horarios">
        <div class="horario">
            <time class="compromisso-inicio">**TIME_START**</time>
                -
            <time class="compromisso-fim">**TIME_END**</time>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="compromisso-dados">
        <h2 class="compromisso-titulo toggle closed">**TITLE**</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to get the values TIME_START, TIME_END and TITLE inside DIV class 'item-compromisso'. I know how to get one of them changing xPath... Example: './/h2[@class="compromisso-titulo"' to get TITLE. But I don't know how to work with childNodes.

Here's my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($url);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$domNodeList = $xPath->query(expression: './/div[@class="item-compromisso"]');

/** @var DOMNode $element */
foreach ($domNodeList as $element) {
    ?
}
```

I really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your actual code use `$xp->query(expression:` exactly like that? If it does, remove `expression:`

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `expression:` and the leading `.` from the initial XPath expression and use a pattern as shown below you will find the root nodes. Iterating through these root nodes you can then form a new expression in the loop to find the nodes of interest but supplying the root node as the 2nd parameter to `xp->query`

```
$url='
    <div class="item-compromisso">
        <div class="compromisso-horarios">
            <div class="horario">
                <time class="compromisso-inicio">**TIME_START**</time>
                    -
                <time class="compromisso-fim">**TIME_END**</time>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="compromisso-dados">
            <h2 class="compromisso-titulo toggle closed">**TITLE**</h2>
        </div>
    </div>';


    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

    $dom=new DOMDocument();
    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->loadHTML( $url );
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $xp = new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $col = $xp->query( '//div[ @class="item-compromisso" ]' );

    if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){
            $start=$xp->query( 'div[1]/div[1]/time[@class="compromisso-inicio"]', $node )->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $end=$xp->query( 'div[1]/div[1]/time[@class="compromisso-fim"]', $node )->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $title=$xp->query('div[2]/h2',$node)->item(0)->nodeValue;
            
            echo $start, $end, $title;
        }
    }
```

This yields: `**TIME_START****TIME_END****TITLE**`

---

**update**

Writing one's own simple function to encapsulate the checking of XPath prior to using the, possibly non-existant, result:

```
function nodevalue($xp,$expr,$ref,$attr=false){
    $col=$xp->query( $expr, $ref );
    if( $col && $col->length == 1 ){
        $node=$col->item(0);
        if( $attr && $node->hasAttribute( $attr ) )return $node->getAttribute( $attr );
        else return $node->nodeValue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And within the loop, call it like this:

```
$start=nodevalue( $xp, 'div[1]/div[1]/time[@class="compromisso-inicio"]', $node ); 
#etc etc etc
```

Comment: Sometimes I don't have the second <TIME> tag... How do I check this avoiding the warning (Warning: Attempt to read property "nodeValue" on null in ...) ?

Comment: Similar to `$col = $xp->query(...)` then `if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){...` - or you use the `$xp->evaluate(...)` method